# R: How to go from a vector of strings to a vector of quotes / names?

Tags: r, evaluation, expression-evaluation

How to get from

```
input = c("a", "b", "c")
```

to

```
output = c(quote(a), quote(b), quote(c))
```

automatically?

Comment: `rlang::syms(input)`??

Comment: @andrew_reece  symbols or formulas or even functions or even quasures can never be stored in a vector. all of them will be stored in a list

Answer (score 6, accepted):

List apply as.symbol() to your input vector.

```
lapply(X = input, as.symbol)
```