# R, data.table: Sum all columns whose names are stored in a vector

Tags: r, data.table, evaluation, expression-evaluation

From a data.table `d` such as for example

```
require(data.table)
d = data.table(a = 1:4, b = 11:14, c = 21:24, group = c(1,1,2,2))
```

I would like to sum all variables which names are stored in the vector `varsToSum` by unique values of `group`.

```
varsToSum = c("a", "b")
```

For the above `d` and `varsToSum`, the expected outcome is

```
d[,list(a = sum(a), b = sum(b)),list(group)]

   group a  b
    1: 1 3 23
    2: 2 7 27
```

---

Related posts:

- [Select / assign to data.table variables which names are stored in a character vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391950/select-assign-to-data-table-variables-which-names-are-stored-in-a-character-ve)
- [How to go from a vector of strings to a vector of quotes / names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710103/r-how-to-go-from-a-vector-of-strings-to-a-vector-of-quotes-names)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
d[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = group, .SDcols = varsToSum]

   group a  b
1:     1 3 23
2:     2 7 27
```