# Iteratively subsetting data.table

Tags: r, data.table

My dataset has a number of duration columns that have both positive and negative values, like this:

```
require(lubridate)
set.seed(43)
dt=data.table(A=as.duration(rnorm(100)*100), B=as.duration(rnorm(100)*100), C=as.duration(rnorm(100)*100))
```

I need to generate summaries for each column, but ONLY for the negative values  in each, like this:

```
a=dt[as.numeric(A)<=0, summary(as.numeric(A))]
b=dt[as.numeric(B)<=0, summary(as.numeric(B))]
c=dt[as.numeric(B)<=0, summary(as.numeric(B))]
results1=data.table(as.list(a),as.list(b),as.list(c))
results1
     V1               V2            V3 
-208.7355428    -237.0840684    -237.0840684 
-109.9255927    -90.91095008    -90.91095008 
-64.83885801    -72.52487746    -72.52487746 
-70.87867962    -74.7173011     -74.7173011 
-25.19085368    -38.76434599    -38.76434599 
-1.009403041    -1.733105648    -1.733105648
```

My dataset has many more columns like A..C, so writing individual summary statements for each variable becomes tedious. Ideally I would like to do this by iterating through each one of those columns. I tried this:

```
for (i in 1:3) {
    #col_name=paste("summary",i,sep="_")
    results[i] = dt[as.numeric(dt[[i]])<=0, .(summary(as.numeric(dt[[i]])))]   
               }
as.data.table(results)
         V1              V2        V3 
1:  -208.7355428    -237.084068 -294.9729 
2:  -64.0973647     -65.496083  -76.02132 
3:  0.1557914       8.544047    14.264934 
4:  6.2315259       9.399898    0.5640193 
5:  58.6766806      76.905693   77.687728 
6:  261.6953128     211.874016  272.82491
```

It seems that in the for loop, the summary is performed on ALL values (both positive AND negative), and the sub setting is being ignored. What am doing wrong? And is there a way to capture the label of each value as well (i.e the row names should be Min, 1stQU, Median, Mean, 3rdQu, Max). Thank you.

Comment: How about the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710266/r-data-table-sum-all-columns-whose-names-are-stored-in-a-vector/50710336#50710336)?  You can easily add a condition to the syntax given there.

Comment: lapply(.SD, function(x) summary (x[x<0]))

Comment: Thank you MichaelChirico , was not aware of  (x[x<0]) syntax. Unfortunately i don't see a way to "accept" your answer.

Comment: Marius: To make sure someone sees your message you can use the @ symbol like “@MichaelChirico please see OP’s request for upgrading from comment to answer above”