# R data.table grouped sum for column referenced by name stored in a variable

Tags: r, data.table

The problem is as follows: I have a data.table with columns A and B. A summary is required and its name is passed as a character vector in variable var1.

I have tried to find an answer for some time now, see e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391950/select-assign-to-data-table-when-variable-names-are-stored-in-a-character-vect) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50710266/r-data-table-sum-all-columns-whose-names-are-stored-in-a-vector) SO posts. Being unable to find a proper solution, I feel forced to ask this myself.

Now what I want to do is (using data.frame)

```
tmp[, var1] <- rep(1, nrow(tmp))
tmp <- aggregate(formula(paste(var1, "~ A + B")), tmp, sum)
```

but I fail to do so with data.table with my last and best effort being

```
tmp <- tmp[, list(..var1 = .N), by = list(A, B)]
```

Now, what is wrong with my code and how do I fix it?

And note that I do NOT want to use the := operator, because I want the result to be exactly as it would be from aggregate().

### Edit 1: A working example:

```
library(data.table)
tmp <- data.table(A=c("R","G","G","B","B","B"), B=c(1,1,1,2,1,2))
print(tmp)

var1 <- "C"

tmp[, var1] <- rep(1, nrow(tmp))
tmp2 <- aggregate(formula(paste(var1, "~ A + B")), tmp, sum)
print(tmp2)

tmp3 <- tmp[, list(..var1 = .N), by = list(A, B)]
print(tmp3)
```

Comment: You should share a minimal [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: Is it enough to just run `setnames(tmp[, .N, by = list(A, B)], "N", var1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope that I did not misread your qn. Here are some options:

**1)** using `base::setNames`

```
DT[, setNames(.(.N), var1), by=.(A, B)]
```

**2)** using `data.table::setnames`

```
setnames(DT[, .N, by=.(A, B)], "N", var1)[]
```

**3)** using `base::structure` followed by `base::as.list`

```
DT[, as.list(structure(.N, names=var1)), by=.(A, B)]
```

data:

```
DT <- data.table(A=c(1,1,2,2), B=c(1,1,2,3))
var1 <- "myCol"
```

Comment: Doing it after the by= like (2) is going to be the most efficient since that uses GForce.

Comment: Yes, (1) is nearest to what I need although far too inelegant to match my expectations of data.table's syntax.